# I2C isolated communication error

Tags: i2c

I'm want to use I2C communication isolated but it's error. I don't know why. My circuit:
[image]

[image]

MCU: STM32F103RDT
ISOLATION IC: Si8600 I2C

Chanel 0: SENSOR_SCL
Chanel 1: SENSOR_SDA
Chanel 2: SCL_ISOLATED
Chanel 3: SDA_ISOLATED

I2C Setting: standard mode - 100kHz
I want to know why waveform I2C Isolation doesn't same as
My English is verry poor. 
Thanks all.

Comment: You could really do with telling us where the error is and what kind of error is happening. That looks like it is working to me.

Comment: I want to know why waveform I2C Isolation doesn't same as

Comment: Do you have bypass caps on the chips? They aren't shown in your schematic.

Comment: Do you have an analogue scope view of the communication? Looks like the signal isn't been read properly, either due to noise or the levels of your various drivers and receivers are not compatible.

Comment: @DoxyLover Yep, I have a 100nF bypass caps for each side.

Comment: @DiepHa - Do you actually have a problem using that device "A1" (marked "Atlas"?) on the isolated I2C bus? Or does that device work OK, and your only question is because the signals on your logic analyser channels 0 & 1 do not *appear* to be the same as on channels 2 & 3?